# Sqlalchemy Sqlite Autoincrement not behaving as expected

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have some trouble making my script incrementing my PK in a correct way. Following the sqlalchemy documentation some special configuration has to be done in order to make it work with sqlite. Here is my script:

```
def db_stuff():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
    metadata = MetaData()
    db = Table('users', metadata,
       Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
       Column('name', String),
       Column('fullname', String),
       Column('password', String),
       sqlite_autoincrement=True)
    metadata.create_all(engine) 
    return engine.connect(),db


def add_to_db():
    ret = db_stuff()
    conn = ret[0]
    db = ret[1]
    try:

        conn.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('1','john','smith john','23')")
        result = conn.execute(db.select())
        for row in result:
            print row 
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

It would be cool if you could help me figuring out what I'm missing here, I start to be desperate...
The problem is that the "id" is not incremented each time and i get an error that it should be unique when I run the script twice.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, fullname, password) VALUES ('john','smith john','23')")
```

id is autoincrement hence we should not pass it, however we need to specify what other parameters represent in the table i.e. where should the values ('john', 'smith john', '23') should go.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('john','smith john','23')")
```

You are setting the id to `1` - always. Just leave it and it will be filled due auto-increment.

Comment: Hello, I tried this already but then I get the following error: table users has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('john','smith john','23')" () I also tried with: conn.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','john','smith john','23')") then i get:  datatype mismatch "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','john','smith john','23')" ()

Comment: Then your id column is not set to auto-increment.

Comment: @user1225343, try to pass `None` for the `id` column

Comment: Try your insert statement in a SQL query tool and see if it works.